# An old deadly killer, what is it?

Tags: riddle

I used to be deadly.
I try to hit you by surprise
but you expect me to.
I can't exist forever,
but I do come back after passing.

What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like

> COVID-19

to me. For certain values of "old", at least.

Comment: Or any number of old diseases, for that matter.